# Space between cells in table

Tags: html, css

I am wondering if there is a way to put a bit of space between cells in a table,

It's a bit of a homemade table using this principle here:

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="tr">
        <div class="td">asdf</div>
        <div class="td">asdf</div>
        <div class="td">asdf</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.table {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.tr { 
    display: table-row; 
}
.td { 
    display: table-cell;
}
```

This isn't the code I use but I built it like this, my code would be a mess to read since its very long, but it works like this, and this is a picture of it.

[image]

So as you can see, its 3 divs, which are each a cell, right now there is space between them using this on the `table` div

```
border-collapse:separate;
border-spacing: 5px;
```

But this gives me a space on the very right and left side as well, I only want it between div nr1-2 and nr2-3, so basically only on both sides of the middle one? Can't use white borders to achieve this since I already use the borders!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `border-spacing: 5px;`, I tried negative `margin` with `position:relative`.

```css
body{
  background: #ccc;
}
div{
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
.table {
display: table;
width: 100%;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
.tr { 
display: table-row; 
}
.td { 
 background: #fff;
display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
  width: 33.333%;
}
.td:first-child{
  left: -5px;
}
.td:last-child{
  right: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
<div class="tr">
    <div class="td">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda doloribus omnis aliquid ea cumque est ipsam praesentium ratione consectetur quis fuga illo cupiditate error, perferendis, veritatis quae soluta suscipit a?</div>
    <div class="td">asdf</div>
    <div class="td">asdf</div>
</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nk4xLdgn/